# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined error in covid tracker app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, leaflet

I am making a covid tracker app in react. For this, I have to make a map but it doesn't get rendered. Also, I'm getting an error while trying to loop through the countries.

I have attached the code snippet. [image]

I am new to react so I dont understand what is wrong with my code.

```
export const prettyPrintStat = (stat) =>
  stat ? `+${numeral(stat).format("0.0a")}` : "+0";

export const showDataOnMap = (data, casesType = "cases") =>
  data.map((country) => (
    <Circle
          center={[country.countryInfo.lat, country.countryInfo.long]}
          fillOpacity={0.4}
          pathOptions={casesTypeColors[casesType].option}
          radius={
            Math.sqrt(country[casesType]) * casesTypeColors[casesType].multiplier
          }
        >
      <Popup>
        <div className="info-container">
          <div
            className="info-flag"
            style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${country.countryInfo.flag})` }}
          ></div>
          <div className="info-name">{country.country}</div>
          <div className="info-confirmed">
            Cases: {numeral(country.cases).format("0,0")}
          </div>
          <div className="info-recovered">
            Recovered: {numeral(country.recovered).format("0,0")}
          </div>
          <div className="info-deaths">
            Deaths: {numeral(country.deaths).format("0,0")}
          </div>
        </div>
      </Popup>
    </Circle>
  ));
```

Comment: you have to post how you are using this component? you might be missing to pass data like `<showDataOnMap data={[1,2,3]} />` also you need read it like `showDataOnMap = ({data, casesType = "cases"})`

Comment: Component name should start with an uppercase: `showDataOnMap`  => `ShowDataOnMap`. And, props destructuring should be done like `({data, casesType = "cases"})`. And, `data` must be an array so that you can use `map()` function on it. Your error message simply means that `data` was `undefined` when you tried to do `map()` on it.

Comment: Thank you. I changed the props destructuring but now I'm getting an error like this. TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'data' of 'undefined' as it is undefined. data is an array.

Comment: Can you create a sandbox with [minimal example code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to reproduce this error? That will help me see the real issue.

Comment: Alright I'll do that